# How to get Raman shift frequency values from neutron scattering measurements?

Tags: spectroscopy, transition-metals, phase, raman, neutrons

I have read some papers that say that a Kohn anomaly mode is a particular feature of 2H- transition metal dichalcogenides and that the existence of such a mode can be seen in neutron scattering data where an anomaly (frequency decrease) in the phonon dispersion plot can indicate a Kohn anomaly. An example of the neutron scattering data for 2H-TaSe2 can be seen below (DOI link to paper:
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.34.734):

[image]

I've seen papers (such as this one: https://doi.org/10.1038/srep02593) say that this anomaly corresponds with a broad peak seen at 140 cm$^{-1}$ but I don't understand how that has been calculated. Does anyone know how the phonon dispersion data like that from neturon scattering experiments can give values corresponding to Raman shift frequencies?

Comment: Photons scattering off of phonons is Raman scattering. Neutrons also scatter off phonons.

Comment: @JonCuster Indeed. I've had another look at the paper and have seen that I had misunderstood it. I believe there is a correspondance between neutron scattering exerpiments and Raman experiments in that both can say something about the phonon energy. I found this link to be useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423969/how-to-convert-cm-1-to-ev